# LogMF showing error when migrated to Log4j2

Tags: log4j, log4j2

My project is currently using log4j1.x version. Now we are converting to log4j2.x

When we removed the log4j1.x jar and put log4j2.x in place, the classes which uses LogMF for logging is showing error.

What is the best alternative for logMF or how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a log4j-1.x adapter but this does not cover the LogMF class.

May I suggest raising this as a question or feature request on the log4j2 issue tracker or mailing list?

---

Update:
Are you aware that with Log4J2, the API has improved so your code can now look like this:

```
logger.debug("Hi {}, my name is {}.", "world", "CoolBird");
```

There are also alternative ways to use the printf format (but the default way seems to have better performance).

Comment: Thanks. yes i tried using the log4j-1.x adapter as well. It doesn't fix the issue. Is there any replacement for LogMF. I tried to include FormattedMessage in log4j2. But it is having different set of parameters.

Comment: Can I use log4j1.x and log4j2 jars in the same project with sperate log4j.xml and lo4j2.xml files?

Comment: There is no replacement for LogMF in log4j2. Log4j2 supports two types of formatting: the SLF4J-like way: `loggger.info("Some {} msg", 33);` and the String.format-like way; `logger.format("Some %d msg", 33);`. It is possible to make the String.format way the default by passing a `StringFormatterMessageFactory` to `LogManager.getLogger(Class, MessageFactory)`. It is not possible to use the log4j-1.x and log4j2 jars together. If you use log4j2 you can only have a single log4j2.xml config file.

Answer (score 1):

I tried ParameterizedMessage in log4j2 as an alternative and it is working fine now.

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/ParameterizedMessage.html

**Example:**

*log4j2*

l4j.debug(new ParameterizedMessage("{} does not match {}", source, p).getFormattedMessage());

*LogMF*

LogMF.debug(l4j, "{0} does not match {1}", source, p);

Comment: Oh dear! Is that what you meant? You don't need to create a new ParameterizedMessage! **Log4J2 does this out of the box!** Just say `logger.debug("Hi {}, my name is {}!", "world", "CoolBird");`